# vxworks msgqueue dump availability

Tags: vxworks

vxworks msg queue is being used for a socket connection. When the size of the queue reaches a particular level(say 5000 bytes) , the receiver at the other side stops reading from the queue due to unknown reason . Due to this , the sender stops responding and the application has to be restarted.
Is there a way by which msg queue contents can be dumped in some file to find out if some sent packet caused the problem ? 
Is there some way to find out why the receiver has stopped reading from  the queue.
Any help highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What error codes do the queue functions return?

Comment: can you please provide some more information on what you did? what system-calls does your application make?